# How to create directory using username within theme

Tags: directory

I have the following code to save the uploaded file to a static directory.

```
<?php
//set the image size in mb
$max_upload_size='10';
$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE = $max_upload_size * 1024 * 1024; 
$uploaddir = './uploads/file/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 
if ($_FILES['uploadfile']['size']<$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
echo "error";
}
}else{
echo"size_error";
}
?>
```

But what I want is to create a username directory under "/uploads/file/". For example if the username is "john", then it should create a folder like "/uploads/file/john/" and saved the file under that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - User needs to be logged in to work

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$uploaddir = './uploads/file/'.$current_user->user_login.'/'; 
wp_mkdir_p( $uploaddir );
```

**Reference -** [`wp_mkdir_p()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mkdir_p) -

Comment: the correct function `is get_current_user();`. but my problem now is it does not create a "username" directory. the file will upload successfully if there is an existing username (i.e. john) directory.

Comment: Call `wp_mkdir_p( $uploaddir);` before you attempt to move the upload.

Comment: @jaypabs The function `get_current_user();` you are refereeing to is a [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) function not a wordpress.